# Try Catch errors when setting attributes

Tags: python

Is there a rule of thumb to follow for error catching while setting attributes of an object? Let's say for example that you have a Shape class as follows:

```
class Shape():
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
```

I can do the following:

> >>> s = Shape(3)
>
> >>> s.size
>
> 3
>
> >>> s.size = "hello"
>
> >>> s.size
>
> 'hello'

But what if the attribute must be numeric? How do I catch TypeErrors in this situation? Do I put a try/except inside the **init** definition? This is my guess:

```
class Shape():
def __init__(self, size):
    try:
        float(size)
        self.size = size
    except:
        raise TypeError, "Value must be numeric"
```

This will catch the error on initialization but not when setting the attribute. How do I catch a TypeError when the user tries s.size = "hello" ?

Thank you!

I tried implementing the answer below and it didn't work:

```
class Shape():
def __init(self, size):
    self.size = size

@property
def size(self):
    return self._size
    
@size.setter
def size(self, value):
    self._size = float(value)
```

I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python_playground.py", line 18, in
>
> ```
> print s.size   File "python_playground.py", line 9, in size
>
> return self._size AttributeError: Shape instance has no attribute '_size'
> ```

Comment: You don't need to use `try/except` here because `float(shape)` already raises a perfectly cromulent exception if the value given can't be converted to a float.

Comment: Your `__init__(self, size)` looks incorrectly specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To validate instance attributes, use properties.

```
class Shape():

    @property
    def size(self):
        return self._size

    @size.setter
    def size(self, value):
        self._size = float(value)
```

Now your `__init__()` method doesn't need to check the values explicitly (because the properties will do that from `__init__()` just as well as from anywhere else) *and* you also get the value checking everywhere else some code tries to set that attribute.

As I noted in a comment on your question, there's no need to use `try/except` here; you'd just be catching one exception to raise another. `float("hello")` already gives you a perfectly reasonable `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'hello'`.

(Of course you now have that `_size` attribute hanging out unprotected, but it's not possible to *truly* protect attributes in Python.)

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion but I meant to say class Shape():
def __init__(self, size):
 with an attribute of "size" not "shape". I implented your idea and it isn't working.

Comment: It "isn't working"? Could you be *slightly* more specific? The code I presented contains no syntax errors and works as described. (I also edited it to use `size` rather than `shape` as the attribute.)

Comment: I used that code and do s = Shape() then do s.size and get this error: Shape instance has no attribute '_size'

Comment: Yes, you have to set it first... I would have thought that would be obvious?